# Express-Session encodes redirect url

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, url-encoding

I want to redirect url in `express`, something like this:

```
res.redirect(301, http://www.ipin.com/search/search.do?searchKey=深圳市佳德发科技有限公司&searchType=inc)
```

`express-session` is very considerate and encodes url to:

```
http://www.ipin.com/search/search.do?searchKey=%F13%02s%B7%D1%D1%80Pl%F8&searchType=inc
```

**How can I redirect with out encoding url?**

---

I found that `res.redirect` does not encode the URL and the problem exists when I add the following `express-session` snippet:

```
  session = require 'express-session'
  app.use(session({
    name: "server-session-cookie-id",
    secret: 'express secret',
    maxAge: 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient, ttl: 260, db: 2}),
  }))
```

If I add this code in my project, it will encode the URL.

Comment: which version of express are you using?  I am using express 4 and it doesn't encode it.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg I use 4.x, I think you are right about express. I have update my problem, I find that if I add session it will encode the url

Comment: are you using bodyparser in your app.js ?

Comment: yes,   `app.use bodyParser.json(); app.use bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})`